# How to get the name of Perl script that is running

Tags: perl

How can I get the name of the script?

For example, I have a Perl script with the name `XXX.pl`. This file contains:

```
$name = #some function that obtains the script's own name
print $name;
```

Output:

```
XXX.pl
```

I would like to liken this to the CWD function that obtains the scripts directory. I need a function that obtains the script's name as well.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The name of the running program can be found in the `$0` variable:

```
print $0;
```

[man perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for other special variables.

Comment: Sometimes the running program will not be the pl file, but a batch job that loaded and ran the pl file.  If your filenames are similar to your package names, print "(" . caller . ")"; is most useful.

Answer (score 50):

```
use File::Basename;
my $name = basename($0);
```

PS. `getcwd()` [and friends](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html#getcwd-and-friends) don't give you the script's directory! They give you the working directory. If the script is in your PATH and you just call it by name, not by its full path, then `getcwd()` won't do what you say. You want `dirname($0)` (dirname also is in `File::Basename`).

Comment: This is incorrect; `dirname($0)` also gives the relative path. If you run a script with `perl script` or `./script`, it will return '.'.

Answer (score 13):

You might also be interested in learning more about [`__FILE__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__FILE__), and possibly [`__LINE__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__LINE__), which gives you the current line and I frequently use together. Both mentioned in [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Special-Literals).

If you want this for debugging purposes, you might also want to learn about [`warn`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn), [`Carp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Carp), [`caller`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller).

Comment: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` aren't required to report the actual values that can be changed with a comment like `# line 42 foo.pl. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Plain-Old-Comments-%28Not%21%29

Answer (score 6):

Check out module [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin), part of the core Perl distribution. It exports variables you're looking for

```
  EXPORTABLE VARIABLES
        $Bin         - path to bin directory from where script was invoked
        $Script      - basename of script from which Perl was invoked
        $RealBin     - $Bin with all links resolved
        $RealScript  - $Script with all links resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this answer, but there's another way from the Perl environment hash `%ENV`.  And since this was the only useful page that came up when I searched, I'll add my way here for people from the future.

`$ENV{'SCRIPT_FILENAME'}`  provides the full path to the script you're running `/var/www/cgi-bin/perlscript.pl`

`$ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'}` provides the chroot path `/cgi-bin/perlscript.pl`

If you want to see all of the environment variables your system provides use the following code:

```
foreach $key (sort(keys(%ENV)))
{
   printf("%16s : %s\n", $key, $ENV{$key});
}
```

I use that loop quite often when I'm examining a new environment.

The reason I'm reading this question is because my work uses ActiveState Perl, and they don't provide the script filename in the environment hash so I was trying to find other ways to get it.  Of all the answers the **only** one that worked in our environment was the `__FILE__`  one listed above.

Comment: Perl doesn't provide that environment for you.`SCRIPT_FILENAME` is typically provided by the CGI protocol, so you won't see this unless the thing that calls your program already set it for you. This has nothing to do with Activestate being somehow different than other perls. Furthermore, `__FILE__` isn't required to report the actual name of the file since that can be changed with a comment like `# line 42 foo.pl. See [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Plain-Old-Comments-%28Not%21%29)

Answer (score 0):

You will get the solution by using **Cwd::abs_path()** as in the code below.
This works in Perl for **Linux** (Debian) as well as in Perl for **Windows**.

The name of the program is prog.pl

Example:

```
use strict;
use Cwd;
use File::Basename;
printf  "\$0 = %s\n" 
    . "Full-Path = %s\n" 
    . "Dir-Path = %s\n", 
    basename( $0 ), 
    Cwd::abs_path( $0 ),
    dirname( Cwd::abs_path( $0 ))
;
```

The output on Linux will be:

```
/storage/tools/test> perl prog.pl
$0 = prog.pl
Full-Path = /storage/tools/test/prog.pl
Dir-Path = /storage/tools/test
```

The output on Windows will be:

```
c:\Temp\storage\tools\test>perl prog.pl
$0 = prog.pl
Full-Path = C:\Temp\storage\tools\test\prog.pl
Dir-Path = C:\Temp\storage\tools\test
```

Bear in mind, that `basename( $0 )` is **essential**. Without basename you will get the answer `prog.pl` only if your current directory is on the same directory level as prog.pl. Otherwise you would get something like `aaa/bbb/prog.pl` depending on the directory you startet the script from.